# Can't determine why exit code is not being logged

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit, exit-status

Weird one, so the following will *not* log "bash exit code..."

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OUTPUT_PATH=${PROJECT_ROOT:-$PWD}/npm-install-output.log

npm --loglevel=warn --progress=false install > ${OUTPUT_PATH} 2>&1 &&
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PATH}:~/.suman/node_modules &&
node $(dirname "$0")/test.js &&

EXIT=$? &&
echo " " && # newline
echo "bash exit code => $?" &&
exit ${EXIT}
```

if I remove one "&&" after the `node` command like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OUTPUT_PATH=${PROJECT_ROOT:-$PWD}/npm-install-output.log

npm --loglevel=warn --progress=false install > ${OUTPUT_PATH} 2>&1 &&
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PATH}:~/.suman/node_modules &&
node $(dirname "$0")/test.js  # <<<<< removed "&&" chars

EXIT=$? &&
echo " " && # newline
echo "bash exit code => $?" &&
exit ${EXIT}
```

then the node process will exit with a non-zero code, but then bash says:

> bash exit code => 0

both of these are not giving correct results, there is something wrong with my code. I want to capture the correct exit code of the node process, and I want to print it out! What could be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$?` is the exit status of your last command. In this case, it always return 0 because `echo " "` was successfull. Please use `$EXIT` instead of `$?`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OUTPUT_PATH=${PROJECT_ROOT:-$PWD}/npm-install-output.log

npm --loglevel=warn --progress=false install > ${OUTPUT_PATH} 2>&1 &&
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PATH}:~/.suman/node_modules &&
node $(dirname "$0")/test.js  # <<<<< removed "&&" chars

EXIT=$? &&
echo " " && # newline
echo "bash exit code => $EXIT" &&
exit ${EXIT}
```